# Salesforce doesn't merge fields on email sent in platform event context

Tags: apex, formula, email-template, merge-field, platform-event

I have a process that runs every day in the morning. It is a scheduled class that publishes a platform event. When this event is run by the system, it collects some records and sends emails to some customers.

This was a process that was not using platform events. I decided to use PEs to get "last modified by automated process" instead of "last modified by {user who scheduled the class}".

Since I deployed this feature, I noticed that some merge fields are not working on the emails. In an attempt to search for a common cause, I can tell that both fields are either formula or retrieve information from the parent record directly, like this:

1. `{!relatedTo.Formula__c}`
2. `{!relatedTo.ParentObject.StringField__c}`

Where the first field is a formula that points to a parent record field, like the second one.

This looks like a permission issue with the user that runs as the system. Anyone with a similar issue?

Comment: fyi, this looks like a similar issue:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/233443/vf-email-templates-boolean-merge-fields-automated-process-user-is-always-false/233523#233523