# Automated Process User Profile Permissions

Tags: visualforce, email-template, permissions, user, admin

We are having some difficulty with permissions. Our admin has also posted on the success board. https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000eB7V, she also found this same posting: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000l9eC I am posting here to see if there are any devs/admins on here that have run into this issue as well.

We have a process that is called from a platform event, which sends a visualforce email template in an email alert. It seems like the Automated Process user, which is the user that triggers the Platform Event, does not have access to the email template's visualforce controller. Is there any way to give access to the controller to that user?

Comment: Are there any profiles which do not have access to that page? Have you tried just giving access to all profiles as a shotgun approach?

Comment: I've had a similar issue, here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/202709/salesforce-doesnt-merge-fields-on-email-sent-in-platform-event-context There's no mention of such limits on the docs.

Comment: @AdrianLarson yea, we gave all available profiles access

Comment: technically, `AutomatedProcess` is the running user that handles the subscription to the ProcessEvent (i.e. the Process Builder or trigger's running user) but not having access to a VF email template's controller would be a bug and should be reported to support.

Comment: There appears to be a knowledge article 000270230 that address this ? - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000270230&type=1

Answer (score 24):

I've found Matt's answer on the [IdeaExchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003aTkQAI)

You can follow the recommendation from [Roy Lloyd](https://trailblazer.me/id/royst) and create a `Permission Set` and assign the `autoproc User` in Exec-Anonymous:

```
insert new PermissionSetAssignment(
    AssigneeId = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE alias = 'autoproc'].Id,
    PermissionSetId = '<your Permission Set Id here>'
);
```

You should then be able to manage the Permission Set to add any new permissions you need.

---

Alternatively, use URL hacking:

Using the Developer Console to query for the **autoproc** Profile ID:

`SELECT ProfileId FROM User WHERE Alias = 'autoproc'`

Then use a URL hack to access the setup page and enable the relevant Apex Classes:

```
/_ui/system/user/ProfileApexClassPermissionEdit/e?profile_id={autoproc_profile_id}
```

Or to Apex Pages

```
/_ui/system/user/ProfileApexPagePermissionEdit/e?profile_id={autoproc_profile_id}
```

Or to Field Level Permissions:

```
/setup/layout/flsedit.jsp?id={autoproc_profile_id}&type={sObjectName}
```

[image: Enable Apex Class Access]

This resolved the error 'You do not have sufficient privileges to access the controller'.

Comment: For anyone else trying to work with custom Objects I had to access it via: 
```/setup/layout/flsdetail.jsp?id={autoproc_profile_id}&type={sObjectId}``` 
Not the name.

Sadly this didn't resolve my issue with merge fields in an email alert triggered by a scheduled flow https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/323774/email-alert-triggered-in-scheduled-flow-has-blank-merge-fields-for-custom-object

Answer (score 1):

If you use an Apex trigger instead of Process as a subscriber, it is possible to specify the running user. This means you no longer have to change the Automated Process User, but can define and use your own user including permissions.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_trigger_config.htm