# Platform Event Apex trigger limits exception - where does it go?

Tags: apex, governorlimits, platform-event

If one publishes a Platform Event, the consuming trigger executes as `Automated Process` user. If that consuming trigger exceeds CPU limits, no notification is sent to the developer(s).

> Even though Apex Exception Email is configured to route to me
>
> Even though my user is configured to get Apex Warning Emails

How does one discover that there was a limits exception so action can be taken?

**Platform Event** `Foo__e`

**Apex Trigger**

```
trigger FooTrigger on Foo__e (after insert) {
    Util.sleep(30); // method that does a CPU sleep of ~arg secs 
}
```

**DeveloperConsole**

```
EventBus.publish(new Foo__e());
```

I have no idea where to find the limits exception email or other indication of failure; querying EventBusSubscriber yields no information re: errors of this sort.

> Support ticket filed

**UPDATE**:

> Lesson to us all: Since a Limits failure fails silently when running
>   user = `Automated Process`, and since your platform event trigger is
>   bulkified; if one event in your batch is, say, exceptionally CPU or
>   heap intensive, the other batch members will fail (silently) as
>   "collateral damage" and be undetected until you do a database audit.
>   Adrian Larson's answer is a practical design way out of this.
>
> Ask me how I know :-(

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but even though platform event threads are considered asynchronous, each platform event thread only gets 10 seconds of CPU instead of 60. My team has tested and confirmed this assertion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My plan to work around this limitation would be roughly as below.

**Configuration**

1. Use a logging object to track each Platform Event you process in your trigger.

   - Make sure this logging object has no required fields nor validation rules.
2. Add a Text (18) field to track `Job_Id__c`.

   - You can later use this field to query `AsyncApexJob`.
3. Add a Text field to track the `Job_Status__c`.
4. Add a TextArea field to track the `Job_Error_Message__c`.

**Code Changes**

1. Move your core logic to a `Queueable`.
2. From your subscriber trigger, fire this async job so any steps which can fail will take place in a separate transaction.
3. From your subscriber trigger, insert a record into your log object.
4. On your log record, set the `Job_Id__c` field.
5. Set up a scheduled batch which iterates over any log records whose `Job_Status__c` is in `(null, 'Holding', 'Preparing', 'Processing')`.

   - Match each `Job_Id__c` up to the corresponding `AsyncApexJob`.
   - Map `Status` to `Job_Status__c`.
   - Map `ExtendedStatus` to `Job_Error_Message__c`.

Comment: N.B. this useful pattern has a side effect of eliminating the utility of `EventBusRetryableException` retry on transient errors like `UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW`

Comment: Can't you replay the event anyway if you track its `ReplayId` on your log? @cropredy

Comment: Yes, there are workarounds.

Comment: I eventually implemented this answer ; note for others: when core logic is in a queueable, if core logic needs to start other (chained) queueables, you are limited to only one child. There are workarounds for this of course.

Comment: NB: Moving logic to a `Queueable` comes at a cost of an async execution (which, sadly, is a limited resource based on the number of, and license types for, your users and the minimum 250000 a day limit). Not an option for us. We've gone down the route of monitoring limits, including CPU limits (with the latter done by collecting average CPU consumption when iterating data to be processed).

Comment: Interesting. I've actually never worked in an org where daily `Queueable` executions were a problem.

Answer (score 4):

A very unsatisfying answer from Support:

> As discussed in the call, the Update that i got from my Product Team
>   is that if a Transaction is executed under the Process Automated User
>   and has failed out due to an Apex Time out limit then there is not
>   gona [sic] be an email sent out as the Automated User doesn't have the level
>   of access to send an email.

and follow up from support ...

> As discussed in the call, the Automated Process User has many process
>   that are runned [sic] under him and if there is a failure because of that
>   then the organisation is gonna [sic] get many emails if there is anything
>   failing out.

You can't have a Production system where if a transaction fails (while running as Automated Process User) due to an uncatchable Limits exception and nobody gets notified.

Possibly related (same root cause ?):

- Automated Process User [can't send VF emails with embedded components](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/231642/for-the-platform-event-automated-process-user-why-do-both-visualforce-control) that have VF controllers ([also this one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/210710/automated-process-user-permissions))
- Not all [merge fields work correctly in VF email templates](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/233443/vf-email-templates-boolean-merge-fields-automated-process-user-is-always-false)

**UPDATE** - [Spring 19 may have a partial solution](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_security_em_eventlogfile_apex_unexpected_exception.htm) to this (props to @danielballinger for pointing this out on Twitter)

> The new Apex Unexpected Exception event type in the EventLogFile
>   object captures information about unexpected exceptions in Apex code
>   execution. The standard way to obtain exception information is from
>   generated email. However, you now have the option of analyzing the
>   EventLogFile object for Apex exception information, including stack
>   traces.

This is most likely an extra cost item as EventLogFile is part of Shield

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_security_em_eventlogfile_apex_unexpected_exception.htm

Answer (score 0):

I do not know direct answer for your question, but I'll post answer just for future reference providing temporal (I hope) workaround.

I went through documentation, developer guides etc, tested what SOQLing EventBusSubcriber shows and didnt find anything that could help and is normally configurable.

So I ended with doing custom solution for that using Limits class, custom object and workflow rule.

So event trigger looks like that (example on DML limits)

```
trigger EventTest on Test__e (after insert) {
   for(Integer i = 0; i < 250; i++){
       if(Limits.getDMLStatements()<Limits.getLimitDMLStatements()-1){
           insert new Account(Name = '5Test' + i);
       } else {

           insert new Error__c(Message__c = 'Limtis reached');
           break;

       }

   }
}
```

Im using Limits class to check if we are reaching limits and if yes I'm inserting custom object (which have field that have email field with default value to email address I want to send to message) and well message.

Rule is firing on record insert.

For workflow rule sender I used org wide email address because Automated Process cant send emails.

Unfortunately I work with limits here like with exception handling. Its troublesome if triggers would be complicated but works.

Comment: yes - avoiding Limits exceptions is of course the best policy. This is somewhat easier to do with SOQL and DML limits and much harder to do with CPU limits as one can not forecast in advance how much CPU time a given statement will incur

Comment: Yeah true that would involve counting time complexity of operations for specific data volume(200 records?) in Salesforce context. Which would be simply pain in the....