# How can Automated Process user get access to REST API class without having to change its Apex Class permissions in the profile?

Tags: apex, permissions, apexrest, platform-event

We have a scenario where from a platform event handler (so user is Automated Process), we could be making a REST API callout to a class belonging to another managed package. Doing so leads to this error:

```
HTTP Status Code: 403Status: ForbiddenBody: [{"errorCode":"FORBIDDEN","message":"You do not have access to the Apex class named: SomeRestAPI"}]
```

All I have been finding is that you have to URL hack the Automated Process user profile to add class permissions, but that is impractical to have every client who wants to use this do this.

Is there some way to get access in Apex when making the callout? In our platform event handler we have the session Id of the user that kicked off the platform event, so tried passing that through an Authorization header, but no luck.

Comment: Have you considered having your platform events run in the context of a given user? See this [Help doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_trigger_config.htm)

Comment: this question might help : use a permission set to give access to the class : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/210710/automated-process-user-profile-permissions?rq=1