# VF email template not showing some case field values when firing through flow

Tags: visualforce, visual-workflow, visualforce-component, vf-email-template, recordtriggeredflow

I have a recordtriggered flow on EmailMessage which fires on incoming emails. Whenever the email message is inserted the recordtriggered flow sends an email alert which is using vf template.

When I see details of case in email I am just seeing case number and id. Other fields like subject, closeddate is not showing any value.

But when I added renderUsingSystemContextWithoutSharing="True" in my vf template rest of the field values is getting displayed in email.

I am not able to understand the concept behind it because the whole process already run as a system user that does not restrict anything as it has access to everything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the running user = `Automated Process` user? If so, that user and VF email templates don't get along -- see [KI](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000jinWAAQ&title=vf-workflow-emails-are-blank-when-the-records-are-last-modified-by-automated-process-user) and [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/233443/vf-email-templates-boolean-merge-fields-automated-process-user-is-always-false)

Comment: @cropredy It's running on the behalf of system user because the email message record is created on the behalf of system user and also when I am printing the current user id in template its giving me the system user.

Comment: instead of using System as automated case user (support settings) , can you change it to be a different user